# MVC3 Registration Form best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a simple register form and I wanted to know if anyone could give me a list of some best practices.  I understand it may differ between registration forms, but maybe some guidelines or things to watch out for like vulnerabilities.  My data access layer will be using Entity FrameWork and linq in order to handle the queries.

Practices that I would think make sense:

- Validate form when the model is binded to the business object (whats the best way to accomplish this?)
- Server-side validation AND client side validation
- Checking for SQL injection? (Any best practices on this?)
- Use dependency injection for my account manager object

My registration fields are going to be the following:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Email (must be an email that HAS to be an email from a select few sites i.e. @gmail.com, @yahoo.com, @live.com)
- School
- Password
- Status (static drop down of 3 or so options)

I would also really like email activation as well where the user would have to go to his or her email in order to make their account active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namesapce for
  validating your view models.
- Yes, do server and client side validations
- Entity Framework already handles SQL injection
- Consider using a "captcha" if you're worried about bots spamming your
  form submissions

For the email part:

In the past, I've created a database table that maps emails to random generated strings. When you send the complete registration email, provide a link that uses that random string or guid or whatever:

`mydomain/completeregistration/7593098573903 whatever`

now, once the client follows that link, and you handle that request, mark their registration as complete in the database. (this should also have the effect preventing subsequent requests to that URL)

Answer (score 2):

Use client side and **Serverside** validation.**Never trust on Client side validation only**.

Use DataAnnotations and jQuery validate pluggin. You do not need to write client side validation function. MVC will do it when you use the HTML Helper methods to render the HTML elements.

Entity Framwork will build parameterized queries. So you do not need to worry about SQL Injection. But if you are manually executing an SQL statement / Stored proc using Entity framework, It is your responsibility to make it parameterized.